# How do I print a svelte app from a browser?

Tags: svelte

I have developed a svelte app and some users want to print the output to a PDF from a browser. The print preview only shows the visible portion of the page and some of the dynamic elements are missing.

I suspect that this is an issue with svelte apps in general as I get a similar result when trying to print svelte's own documentation -

[image]

Are there any techniques that I can use to print what the user sees, including all of the page, not just the visible portion?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this to be a problem for most SPA frameworks and not only Svelte since Javascript execution is needed to hydrate dynamic content which won't happen with native priting.

What you can do is adding a "Print" button on your website and generate a pdf dynamically & programmatically using one of [PDF Generation packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=pdf%20generator)